# Xamarin Forms ListView selection-background paints over an item-background

Tags: ios, iphone, xaml, xamarin.forms

For a xamarin forms project on my iPhone/iOS (12.4), I'm using ItemTemplate to showing ViewCells of a ListView.
This looks like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid>
            ...
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource PositionToBackgroundColorConverter}}"
                    BorderColor="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource PositionToTextColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static model:ItemComponent.Border}}">
                ...
```

This works pretty fine, sofar a selected item is not set. When I select an item, the selected row are drawing by the framework, and its background is set to gray. In this state the background of the frame is not drawn correctly. Or the background of the selection "overpainting" the background of the frame.

Do you know a (simple?) method to redraw the Frame, after the selected item is changed?

**EDIT**:

For example, to easier understanding the problem, I put here an image with two ViewCells. The first ListItem is not selected, the second ListItem is selected. This is a symbolic illustration of unwanted behavior!

[image: symbolic illustration]

When the ListItem is selected it should looks like this here:

[image: Right view]

Comment: Do you want to remove the selecteditem state?

Comment: Please see my additional explanation

Comment: I'm afraid you can't achieve what you want with the default selection behavior. What I recommend you to do is binding the background color of ViewCell and change the color in [itemselected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.itemselected?view=xamarin-forms) event.

Comment: I can not taste it right now, but when I have time again, I try to follow your idea. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, let me know if it works once you have tried.